# AWSSDK S3 for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have tried to upload file to Amazon S3 using AWSSDK for .NET Core, but I always got exception like below:

> The write operation failed, see inner exception.
>
> The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

No matter connect to Singapore (Global) or Beijing (cn-north-1), it still has problem.

Can anyone give me some suggestions to solve this problem?

This is version and codes, please!

> .NET Core / 1.1.1
>   AWSSDK.S3 / 3.3.5.10

**Startup.cs**

```
// Add framework services.
services.AddMvc();
services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
```

**appsettings.json**

```
"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "xxxxxxxxxx",
"AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"AWS": {
  "Region": "cn-north-1",
  "ServiceURL": "https://s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn"
}
```

**Controller**

```
private readonly IAmazonS3 _AmazonS3Client;

public UsersController(
       IAmazonS3 AmazonS3Client)
{
     _AmazonS3Client = AmazonS3Client;
}


[HttpPost]
[Route("users/picture/upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadUserPhoto(string UserId)
{
    Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse response = await 
       _AmazonS3Client.PutObjectAsync(
       new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest()
       {
           BucketName = "mybucket",
           Key = fileName,
           InputStream = uploadFiles[0].OpenReadStream(),
           CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
       });
}
```